# Salesforce - AWS S3 : Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, apex

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with AWS S3 via REST.

```
Attachment attach = [
    select Body,
        ContentType,
        Name
    from Attachment
    limit 1
];

String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(attach.Body);
String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().formatGMT('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z');
String key = 'xxxx';
String secret = 'xxxx';
String bucketname = 'kvntest';
String host = 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com';
String method = 'PUT';
String filename = attach.Id + '-' + attach.Name;

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod(method);
req.setEndpoint('https://' + bucketname + '.' + host + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename);
req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
req.setHeader('Content-type', attach.ContentType);
req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read');
req.setBody(attachmentBody);

String stringToSign = 'PUT\n\n' +
    attach.ContentType + '\n' +
    formattedDateString + '\n' +
    '/' + bucketname + '/' + bucketname + '/' + filename;

String encodedStringToSign = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(stringToSign, 'UTF-8');
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(secret));
String signed = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
String authHeader = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + signed;
req.setHeader('Authorization',authHeader);
String decoded = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(encodedStringToSign , 'UTF-8');

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('*Resp:' + String.ValueOF(res.getBody()));
System.debug('RESPONSE STRING: ' + res.toString());
System.debug('RESPONSE STATUS: ' + res.getStatus());
System.debug('STATUS_CODE: ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

The above is my anonymous apex code.

For some reason I keep on getting this error response stating that I need to use SHA256 eventhough I am indeed using that algo to encrypt.

[image]

```
<Message>The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message><RequestId>C06368F096704377</RequestId><HostId>PloPZ5YnUD0vRyIg/uvcLRHFBpYoRBBVTCyEXIwK2wQvXUahnsPRnZxSqEyEARJeWVeVpS4fKuc=</HostId></Error>
```

Can someone give me some pointers as to what I have been doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

us-east-2 [only supports signature v4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) but seems that you are using signature v2. So, you must use SigV4 to sign the request. Some examples can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html). Hope this helps.